# OpenGL 3.2 not supported

Tags: java, opengl

So, I have been working on a Java game with OpenGL 3.2. But when I try to test my game, I get the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Profiles are only supported on OpenGL version 3.2 or higher.
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextAttribs.withProfileCore(ContextAttribs.java:188)
    at renderEngine.DisplayManager.createDisplay(DisplayManager.java:18)
    at engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:12)
```

So OpenGL 3.2 is not supported, what do I do? Buy a new graphics card or Can I download drivers?

Comment: check the site of your card's vendor

Comment: Or your card might already support it but you've requested a context that's a different version?  How do you initialise OpenGL?

Comment: I have set up LWJGL for my project, and the slick util. How i initialize LWJGL: `import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;`

Comment: What I mean is LWJGL context attributes, i.e.  http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/Version_selection.

Comment: Robinson, thanks for your help, but there was a other problem. I just had to update my graphics card, lol I'm so dumb. Thanks for your help anyways!